# Trying To Pass Functions as Paramater Gives "Function name must be a string"

Tags: php, slim

So I'm developing an app with the Slim framework for php, I am trying to write a custom route "helper" to make adding routes a little easier and I'm getting the error "Function name must be a string" when trying to run the code.

This is my route helper:

```
<?php
namespace XSC\API\Core;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class RouteHelper {
        public static $request;
        public static $response;

    public static function registerRoute($route, $callback) {
            Slim::$instance->get($route, function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
                self::$request = $request;
                self::$response = $response;

                $callback(self::$request, self::$response, $args);

                return self::$response;
            });
    }
}
```

And this is the route:

```
<?php
namespace XSC\API\Routes;

use XSC\API\Core\RouteHelper;
use XSC\API\Minecraft;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

RouteHelper::registerRoute('/minecraft/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    Minecraft\Rcon::connect('all-the-mods-');

    $response->getBody()->write(Minecraft\Rcon::command("testing 123"));

    Minecraft\Rcon::disconnect();
});
```

I've been looking for a solution for about an hour, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: Function name must be a string in which line and file?

Comment: The $callback(...) line [16]. It's fixed now I forgot to pass the $callback variable to the function with use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following

```
<?php
namespace XSC\API\Core;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    class RouteHelper {
            public static $request;
            public static $response;

        public static function registerRoute($route, $callback) {
                Slim::$instance->get($route, function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) use ($callback) {
                    self::$request = $request;
                    self::$response = $response;

                    $callback(self::$request, self::$response, $args);

                    return self::$response;
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: "use" keyword is added at the end of second callback in get function

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I forgot to forward the $callback to the actual function. +1